# Navigate PDF File using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I have a question about PDF files with Jquery.

Though most browsers has an embedded PDF Viewer, but what i need is something totally different.
while i was browsing IKEA Catalouge http://onlinecatalogue.ikea.com/TR/tr/IKEA_Catalogue/
i found it simple and professional, viewing the catalouge this way is so easy and nice, but on the other hand it's using Flash which I don't recommend ! 
So, is there any possible way to read the content of a PDF File using Jquery and then i will write the arrow keys function to go to the next page or go back and so on ?

Waiting your help and Ideas.

Comment: check http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/09/best-jquery-pdf-viewer-plugin-examples/

Comment: @AbhasTandon thnx for your reply. i've already stopped by this, but they are displaying the content only, there is no control on the pages.

Comment: Whether controls work, depends on the viewer. Probably the simplest (and widest understood) control is a Link. So, what you would have to do is adding Links at the particular location, and have the link go to the next page. (this is kind of a shift of the problem to something which has more likely been done).

Comment: any new ideas ? i'm still stuck in the same place